# Make a c++ project in eclipse

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, c++

I installed eclipse, jdk ,gcc and g++. When I open eclipse and want to make a new project, I have no option for a c++ project. 
what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you download the correct eclipse enviroment?
Checking the eclipse website: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/c.php

Verify if you download the correct enviroment, if not go to the link above.
Hope it helps you.